# The use of NOT EXISTS in SQL

Tags: sql

If table A has an int num and table B has an int q

Do the following two queries always give the same result?

Q1:

```
select num
from A
where num>any(select q from B)
```

Q2:

```
select num
from A
where not exists(select * from B where num<=q);
```

Thank you

Comment: Answer: suppose `num` is NULL (or `q` is NULL). What will happen? Answer2: inspect the query plans.

Comment: suppose `B` has a column `num`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're quite different. The first one looks for `A` records where `A.num` is greater than *some* `B.q`; that is, if there's *any* `B.q` that's less than a given `A.num`, then that `A.num` will appear in the result. The second one looks for `A` records where `A.num` is greater than *all* `B.q`s; that is, any `B.q` that's *not* less than a given `A.num`, then that `A.num` will *not* appear in the result.

Assuming that the second query is approximately what you wanted, then you should change `ANY` to `ALL` in the first query.

Even then, however, there's a difference, in that they handle nulls differently:

- If `B.q` is ever null, then the version with `ALL` will never return any rows (because the null is taken to mean "unknown", so potentially arbitrary large, and the `WHERE` clause only accepts rows that are *known* to meet the condition), whereas the version with `NOT EXISTS` will simply ignore those nulls (since they're filtered out by the inner `WHERE` clause).
- If `A.num` is ever null, then the version with `ALL` will omit those nulls (since they're filtered out by the `WHERE` clause), whereas the version with `NOT EXISTS` will include them (since they're filtered out by the *inner* `WHERE` clause).

(**Edited to add:** As [dav1dsm1th](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766872/dav1dsm1th) implies in a comment above, this assumes that `B` does not have any column named `num`. If `B` *does* have a column named `num`, then the version with `NOT EXISTS` is actually referring to `B.num` rather than `A.num`, and its behavior is again completely different from the version with `ALL`. This can be fixed by explicitly writing `A.num` rather than simply `num` in the subquery.)

Comment: I think you have the logic wrong.  The first is saying the `A.num` is bigger than the minimum of `B.q`.  The second is saying that there are no rows in B where `A.num` is less than the value.  This is a double negative, which gets you to `A.num` is bigger than some value of `B.q` -- which is the same as saying that `A.num` is bigger than the minimum value of `B.q`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff as you said, but the double negative means that the 2nd query is like saying hat `A.num` is bigger than the **maximum** value of `B.q`